# Python: How to use or get the column header in Pandas and use it as input/value

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following script that produces an empty DataFrame using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Creating a list of row headers with dates.
start=datetime.date(2017,3,27)
end=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
row_dates=[x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for x in pd.bdate_range(start,end).tolist()]
identifiers=['A','B','C']
#Creating an empty Dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(index=identifiers, columns=row_dates)

print(df)
```

Now, suppose I have a function (let's call it "my_function(index,date)") that requires two inputs: an index, and a date.

That function gives me an outcome and I want to fill the corresponding empty slot of the dataframe with that outcome. But for that, I need to be able to acquire both the index and the date.

For example, let's say I want to fill the first slot of my DataFrame, I require index 'A' and the first Date which is '27/3/2017', so I have this:

my_function('A', '27/3/2017')

How can I make that happen for my entire DataFrame? My apologies if any of this sounds confusing.

Comment: Can you use .loc indexing?

`def my_function(index, date):
    df.loc[index, date] = some_value`

Comment: The function is already defined, all I care about is how I use the corresponding index and date values from the names of the corresponding row and header.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over every cell in the dataframe, and apply a function to each cell?

Comment: Something like this? `for col in df.columns:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        print(row[0], col)`

Answer (score 0):

Added to the end of your code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        print(row[0], col)
```

That prints (returns) a tuple, consisting of the index (date) and the column name. There may be a faster way to do it.

If you want to just apply a function to every cell in your df, you can use .apply, .map, or .applymap, as necessary. https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes.html